# Distinct result problems - SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 3 tables (Incident, phonecallevent, eventreason)

The incident table stores all the information related to an incident and the ponecallevent table stores the information regarding the calls made to report incidents. The problem is that for one incident there may be several calls, to give you a small example of what I currently need I have this query:
(UID: Incident / Name: Reason for call)

```
SELECT DISTINCT inc.uid, er.Name
FROM [Incident] Inc INNER JOIN
[PhoneCallEvent] PCE ON PCE.IncidentRefs = INC.GID INNER JOIN
[EventReason] ER ON ER.GID = PCE.eventReasonGID
```

Example result:

| UID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| INC 15128238 | Without energy |
| INC 15128237 | Without energy |
| INC 15128248 | Intermittent service |
| INC 15128248 | Existence of Danger |
| INC 15128248 | Without energy |

The problem is that the incident INC 15128248 has 3 calls and in all 3 of them a different reason was reported. In those cases in which there is more than one reason for an incident, I need to show only the first one and avoid repeating the incident several times .

The result should look like this:

| UID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| INC 15128238 | Without energy |
| INC 15128237 | Without energy |
| INC 15128248 | Intermittent service |

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have more columns to determine which row came first? Show the tables schema and add data samples

Answer (score 0):

Using a [common table expression](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-common-table-expressions-cte/) (or CTE) and [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) [window function](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/)

```
   WITH OrderedReasons AS (
        SELECT
            inc.uid,
            er.Name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY inc.uid ORDER BY pce.EventDateTime) AS RowNum
        FROM
            [Incident] inc
            INNER JOIN [PhoneCallEvent] pce ON pce.IncidentRefs = inc.GID
            INNER JOIN [EventReason] er ON er.GID = pce.eventReasonGID
    )
    SELECT
        uid,
        Name
    FROM
        OrderedReasons
    WHERE
        RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number()` window function with common table expression.  To get the earliest call you need to order your data. In place of `YourOrderByCOlumnName` you can use call datetime column or something like that. Below query will return one row per inc.uid :

```
with cte as
(SELECT DISTINCT inc.uid, er.Name,row_number()over(partition by inc.uid order by YourOrderByCOlumnName)rn
FROM [Incident] Inc INNER JOIN
[PhoneCallEvent] PCE ON PCE.IncidentRefs = INC.GID INNER JOIN
[EventReason] ER ON ER.GID = PCE.eventReasonGID
)
select uid,name from cte where rn=1
```